# NSNotificationCenter is not getting called when changing class

Tags: ios, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

Hello I am calling a NSNotificationCenter whenever I am getting a notification in my application. I knew one that in order to make NSNotificationCenter to work we have to add it first and then we have to call it. I am already doing this thing in my Home Class. In order to notifications to work a user has to **Login** first. After Login it will go to Home screen where I am adding observer for NSNotificationCenter.

My concept is that when ever my App is in active state then for that I am showing a custom NotificationPopUp.

The problem I'm facing is when I switch class say I go to **profile** class from **Home** Class then for some reason my NSNotificationCenter is not getting called. I am not removing observer for the same NSNotificationCenter anywhere in my class. And when I come back to the same **Home** class again then my NSNotificationCenter is getting called and customNotiPopUp is showing. I really don't know what is the problem I am facing as I am not using remove observer for the same.

I am using SWREveal Controller as a SideMenuoption for navigation to different classes. Is this thing creating problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't add your `NSNotificationCenter` each and every class. Use that in `Appdelegate` class. If you want custom `Alert` show it in `subview` of `UIWindow`, Do you want default `UIAlertViewController` get current visible `UIViewController` from `UINavigationController`. Check if your app support `UIAlertViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I have solved the problem. Actually I am taking a baseclass for every class and in that I have added the observer now it's working perfect as expected. It was a  silly mistake by me.